# When was Judgment day in the Terminator Series?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines, terminator-salvation

### When was Judgement day to happen or suppose to happen in **EACH** of the Terminator movies?

- Terminator 1

  I don't think we are told yet when Judgment day will be.
- Terminator 2

  Sarah Connor was always saying in the psychiatric hospital interviews to Silberman about Judgement day being on August 29, 1997. And we have conformation of this by the Terminator himself.
- Terminator 3

  I am not sure where I got this from but, I was under the impression that Judgment day for T3 was July 25 2004.
- Terminator 4

  I am not sure, but I was under the impression that Judgment Day for T4 was the same as T3.
- Terminator 5

  I have no idea when Judgment day was to take place.

### Is there any canon information as to when each movie's "Judgement Day" was supposed to occur?

Answer (score 5):

All known ["Judgement Days"](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Judgment_Day)

- August 29, 1997 from *Terminator 2: Judgment Day*
- July 25, 2003 from *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*
- July 25, 2004 from *Terminator Salvation*
- April 21, 2011 from *The Sarah Connor Chronicles*

These are the known dates, however since time-travel is a big component to the series it is difficult to determine which events have or will change the date of Judgment Day.

The ending of *Terminator Genisys* again leaves this ambiguous, but impies that Judgement Day will occur sometime in 2017.

Comment: Yeah Genisys was something that I just could get anything on. UV for the nice work.

Comment: @KyloRen Gotta leave the series open for more sequels!!! The real "judgment Day" occurs when the franchise is no longer profitable :-$

Comment: Too true, too true.

Comment: In Terminator, Kyle indicates that he was serving with Perry "***From ‘21 to ‘27***". That places the *lower bound* on Judgment Day as being no later than 2021.

Comment: He also says *"Sarah was shaking her head. “I’m not stupid, you know. They can’t make things like that yet.” Reese nodded. “No,” he said, “not yet. **Not for about forty years.**”"* again, placing judgement day in the late 2010s or early 2020s